# Why is one div higher than the other?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have these two divs floated to the left but for some reason one is coming out higher than the other What's causing this?

[image]

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .address-summary {
        float: left;
        margin: 10px;
    }
</style>

<h2>CheckoutSummary</h2>

<div>
    <div class="address-summary">
        Shipping To:
        <ul>
            <li>@Model.ShippingAddress.Street</li>
            <li>@Model.ShippingAddress.City, @Model.ShippingAddress.State @Model.ShippingAddress.Zip</li>
            <li>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ShippingAddress.Phone1)</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear-fix"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        Billing To:
        <ul>
            <li>@Model.BillingAddress.Street</li>
            <li>@Model.BillingAddress.City, @Model.BillingAddress.State @Model.BillingAddress.Zip</li>
            <li>@Model.BillingAddress.Phone1</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear-fix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `margin` around `.address-summary` that's pushing the div down.

Comment: Oh for goodness sake. I forgot to apply the class to the second div otherwise they would have been pushed down equally. :/

Answer (score 1):

this

```
 .address-summary {
        float: left;
        margin: 10px;  <<<<<
    }
```

It's adding a margin of 10px on all edges of the div (including the top).

The way `margin` and `padding` are written is:

```
margin: top right down left;
```

e.g.

```
/* Div has 10px margin all around: */
margin: 10px;

/* Applies 10px to top and bottom margin, and 15px to left and right margins: */
margin: 10px 15px; 

/* Applies 10px margin to top, 15px to both left and right, and 12px to bottom: */
margin: 10px 15px 12px;

/* Apples 10px to top, 15px to right, 12px to bottom, and 13px to left: */
margin: 10px 15px 12px 13px;
```

Answer (score 1):

because your margin: 10px;

with margin you do in all front your div

use this

```
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
```